# Firebase RTDB rules issue

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to control the incoming traffic better in my RTDB to get rid of this persistent email that my rules are unsafe. It is a single chat project, the only project/folder in my google Firebase db, so i thought these rules would be sufficient,

```
{
     "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null"
     }
    }
```

**Your security rules are not secure. Any authenticated user can steal, modify, or delete data in your database.**

one authorized chat user needs to read another authorized users posts to the db right? well i did email support and that did get some answers but a novice isn't capable of digesting it to what i want the rules to do, please help.
I desperately want RTDB rules that says "nobody can do anything to the db unless they have something in the db user field 'plan="", like i use in Firestore Database when i want to do localhost dev in peace and quiet.

```
 rules_version = '2';

    //from original but waste comments removed 

    service cloud.firestore {

      match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /{document=**} {

        //modified here to lockout all new registration

        //change to original when site ready for launch

                allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.plan != null 

         allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.plan != null

       }

      }

    }
```

this locks out anyone that doesn't already have a paid subscription in the db. I love this i want this in RTDB...but im a novice that can not learn and digest the language needed to be used in RTDB rules....gah!im not sure how i hacked that together, maybe bard helped i dont remember... languages, languages, prefixes....im trying everyone! but i need a mulligan.

what i tried;
RTDB rules don't iterate like Firestore Database rules....WHY!? i don't know but it has crushed any desire for me to 'playground' rules...just go straight to experts. I did playground some modded rules but not understanding the language was worthless sandboxing